# Custom CSS font disapears after clicking on link

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a basic HTML/CSS website for fun and put a custom font on it. The problem is that when ever I click on a link on my sidebar the custom font changes to a standard font, and won't revert to the custom font unless I close the tab and re-open it. How can I get it to stay?

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'VHS';
src: url('http://hashfastr.com/fonts/VHS.ttf');
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

.upper {
    font-family: 'VHS';
    font-size: 400%;
    color: white;
}

.lower {
    font-family: 'VHS';
    font-size: 300%;
    color: white;
}

.mini {
    font-family: 'VHS';
    font-size: 150%;
    color: white;
}

.list {
    font-family: 'VHS';
    font-size: 100%;
    color: white;
}
```

The website is [here](http://www.hashfastr.com)

Edit: The problem does not work on mobile, only chrome and firefox. I assume this is due to a caching error?

Comment: My guess is that you are caching the old font. Have you tried forcing your cache to clear by holding down `SHIFT` while clicking the refresh icon?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I tried that, doesn't work. Problem also persists in chrome and firefox.